# C# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method TryGetValue

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I know that lots of question related to this error, but I can not find out a way to convert my query to meet my query. My error: '`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean TryGetValue(Int32, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]] ByRef)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`'
My mind is melting down!

```
var groupedKeyAndValueOfProjectIdAndZoneIds = groupedProjectDelegationByProjectId.ToDictionary(keySelector: x => x.ProjectId, elementSelector: x => x.ZoneIds);
```

...

```
var data = projects
                        .Select(p => new Project
                        {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            ProjectName = p.Name,
                            Zones = p.Zones.Where(z =>
                              (zoneIds.Contains(z.Id) || (groupedKeyAndValueOfProjectIdAndZoneIds.TryGetValue(p.Id, out outValue) ? outValue.Contains(z.Id) : false)))
```

...
Given that groupedKeyAndValueOfProjectAndZones is `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`.
Please help me.

Comment: Why don't you take the little effort to make your question a bit more readable? It's those little things that help you get answers quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to mix two sources of data together. Underneath the hood LINQ to Entities wants to take the expression you are expressing in LINQ and translate it into a SQL query. In other words when you are writing a select in LINQ you are getting 1:1 mapping in SQL. When you throw a dictionary of data the way `groupedKeyAndValueOfProjectAndZones` is into the mix LINQ to Entities doesn't know how to represent this as its an in memory data source that has no SQL equivalent to run.

To fix this you need to either move the data contained in `groupedKeyAndValueOfProjectAndZones` into the database and query it from there or you need to provide the filtering you are doing post the LINQ to Entities query